# What does the ".1." at the end of a bstrProgId as string mean/do?

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, controls

when dynamically creating a userform layout, whilst adding controls, I found out that the syntax requires a ".1" at the end of the bstrProgId as string in the following bits of code:

```
For loopthroughsteps = 0 To 0
    For foodgroup_id = 0 To 6
        'For vit = 2 To 18
        For vit = 2 To 3
            Dim listbox As Object
            Set listbox = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.Listbox.1", foodgroup_id & "-" & vit & "-" & loopthroughsteps, True)                
            With listbox
                .Left = 35 * (vit - 1) + 205 * (vit - 2)
                .Top = 25 + (foodgroup_id) * 50
                .Height = 50
                .Width = 205
            End With
        Next vit
    Next foodgroup_id
Next loopthroughsteps
```

what does the ".1" after `Controls.Add("Forms.Listbox` do or mean?

I could not find it in the documentation, but I was curious;

- is it an index for the control form, but then why is it (always) 1?
  and why would it be a number in a string?
- or is it an indication of some sort, if so for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add(ProgID, Name, Visible)
```

The first parameter `progID` is just a string, that the COM factory parses and decides which object to create. It is not specified to be exactly the programmatic name of the class (i.e. the `typename`), but a string that the object factory maps to a given class.

Why is it `"Forms.Listbox.1"` and not `Forms.Listbox`? The reasons behind that ".1" is related to the implementation, most likely due to "versioning" within the development team that develops and maintains VBA. A developer just needs to use the specified string "progID" as documented in the `UserForm.Add` method.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other good answer here is some documentation (too much for a comment) ...

If you poke around the registry using `Regedit.exe` specifically the CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID hive then you will see something like this

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{884e2013-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09}]


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{884e2013-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09}\ProgID]
         @="X509Enrollment.CAlternativeName.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{884e2013-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09}\VersionIndependentProgID]
         @="X509Enrollment.CAlternativeName"
```

Thus one can see a `ProgID` and a `VersionIndependentProgID`.  With this one can control the version of the control one wants to instantiate.

Here is a Microsoft documentation link 
[VersionIndependentProgID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542717(v=vs.85).aspx)